# How to get the weights associated with a hidden layer in TF?

Tags: tensorflow

I need to extract the weights of each hidden layer in my model.

I tried using tf.get_variable but I run into an error.

```
#hidden layer 1
h1= tf.layers.dense(x,1024, kernel_initializer="he_normal", activation = "relu")

#get weights
with tf.variable_scope("h1", reuse=tf.True):
    weights_h1 = tf.get_variable("kernel")
```

This is the error I get:

```
ValueError: Variable h1/kernel does not exist, or was not created with tf.get_variable(). Did you mean to set reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE in VarScope?
```

Comment: Your layer needs to be explicitly called `h1`/be created inside the scope.

Comment: @xdurch0 I don't quite understand

Comment: You are trying to get weights with the name `h1/kernel`. But you never named your hidden layer `h1` so the weights won't have that name. The fact that the _Python variable_ for the layer is called `h1` doesn't matter, you will actually need to pass `name=h1` or something like that when creating the layer.